# On click move option to next select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to move each option on click to next select, here is what currently I have got:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
<select multiple name="players" id="players">
    <option value="player">player</option>
    <option value="player1">player1</option>
    <option value="player2">player2</option>
</select>


<select multiple name="team" id="teams">
    <option value="team">team</option>
    <option value="team1">team1</option>
    <option value="team2">team2</option>
</select>
```

```
  $('#players option').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#teams');
  });
});

  $('#teams option').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#players');
  });
});
```

The problem is when I click on already appended element, it just don't want to move to "original" select. How to fix it?

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ujugej/4/edit

Comment: you can't bind events to `option` tag in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're assigning the events at the start, before anything has been moved. Instead, assign the events to the parents that aren't going to change, and delegate it to the options. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$('#players').on('click', 'option', function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#teams');
});

$('#teams').on('click', 'option', function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#players');
});
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ujugej/9/)

Comment: will fail in IE, doesn't support events on `option` tag